# How to cover a div with another div

Tags: jquery, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-draggable

Say I have divs B-Z all over my webpage. I have `div` A, which is inserted at the very beginning with

```
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
```

which basically spans the entire browser page. However, `div` A is hidden.

Now, I am trying to implement a file upload drag-n-drop feature. The idea is this: `div` A is hidden as soon as the page loads, and remains hidden until the user drags a file onto the browser. At this point, `div` A shows itself, covering all other elements, then after the drop, it hides itself again.

After realising that the jquery/ember `dragLeave` event fires upon entering or leaving any child element, I am now looking for a way to have a div blanket all other elements so that any and all mouse events that occur on `div` A are not even registered for the elements underneath it. In fact, the other elements shouldn't even be seen when this `div` shows. Kind of like a photoshop layer.

I've tried `Z-index` to no avail.

Just to be clear, `divs` B-Z are not child elements of `div` A; `div` A is simple inserted before all other `div`s.

Comment: As per your question, below `Dusty` answer should be the answer. `z-index` in `CSS`.

Comment: why not hide the other divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

div A should be AFTER all the other divs if you want it to be on top of them (this will work without a z-index).  a positive z-index should work as long as the other elements do not have a z-index as well.

Comment: well, that was easy. Thank you very much. Just to clarify, is it that every div placed after A will be placed over A because A's position is absolute?

Comment: Since A is absolute, it is taken out of the flow of the page. This means the other divs are placed as if A does not exist. Since the order of the elements determines which is in front, everything after A will be placed on top of it.